# Inno Setup creates installer without including application

Tags: inno-setup

I have added my application to the installation script, but when the program builds the main.exe (Go) application installer, my application is not included in the installer.

The installer installs the target application as expected, but the program exits instantly when executed.

The Go program is about 8mb, and the installer is 1.5mb. When compiling, if I miss-spell the name of my application it fails to build, proving that it is linked to the correct main.exe application in some way.

I'm running Windows 8 64 bit, here is the installer script that Inno Setup uses (taken from 64 bit example):

```
[Setup]
AppName=TokenServer
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\TokenServer
DefaultGroupName=TokenServer
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\TokenServer.exe
Compression=lzma2
SolidCompression=yes
OutputDir=g:/_GOLANG/tokenserver/output
ArchitecturesAllowed=x64
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
[Files]
Source: "main.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName: "TokenServer.exe"
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\TokenServer"; Filename: "{app}\TokenServer.exe"
```

Compile Log:

```
 *** Starting compile.  [12:00:42]

[ISPP] Preprocessing.
[ISPP] Preprocessed.

Parsing [Setup] section, line 3
Parsing [Setup] section, line 4
Parsing [Setup] section, line 5
Parsing [Setup] section, line 6
Parsing [Setup] section, line 7
Parsing [Setup] section, line 8
Parsing [Setup] section, line 9
Parsing [Setup] section, line 10
Parsing [Setup] section, line 13
Parsing [Setup] section, line 17
Reading file (WizardImageFile)
   File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\WIZMODERNIMAGE.BMP
Reading file (WizardSmallImageFile)
   File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\WIZMODERNSMALLIMAGE.BMP
Preparing Setup program executable
Reading default messages from Default.isl
Parsing [LangOptions], [Messages], and [CustomMessages] sections
   File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\Default.isl
   Messages in script file
Reading [Code] section
Parsing [Icons] section, line 23
Parsing [Files] section, line 20
Reading version info: G:\_GOLANG\tokenserver\main.exe
Deleting setup.exe from output directory
Creating setup files
   Compressing: G:\_GOLANG\tokenserver\main.exe
   Compressing Setup program executable
   Updating version info

*** Finished.  [12:00:55, 00:12.250 elapsed]
```

Comment: Can you include InnoSetup compiler log?

Comment: @martin-prikryl added console log, thanks

Comment: it clearly spends the correct amount of time while compressing the main.exe during compilation (judging by compression speed and time taken)

Answer (score 0):

Did you compare the installed `TokenServer.exe` with source `main.exe`?

Note that the installer can be smaller than the installed application, because it is compressed.

I guess that the problem is you did not include some .dll the application depends on.

Comment: Golang doesn't use any DLL files, I meant to say the installed application was 1.5 mb. There is no compression on earth that can compress arbitrary files of 8+mb into 1.5 mb.